# Redirect old domain to new domain

Tags: apache, .htaccess, redirect

I want to redirect the home page to another page in the new domain

```
www.domain.com www.newdomain.com/landing
www.domain.com/es www.newdomain.com/es/landing
www.domain.com/en www.newdomain.com/en/landing
```

The others page differente of the home, I can redirect with the rule "Redirect 301", but, When I want the redirect the home page It's turn crazy

example

```
Redirect 301 / /www.newdomain.com/landing
Redirect 301 /es /www.newdomain.com/es/landing
Redirect 301 /en /www.newdomain.com/en/landing
```

In the home multilanguage, redirect to www.newdomain.com/landinges

Exist another way? I try with Rewrite Rule, but doesn't work or I add incorrectly the code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Redirect 301 /` will redirect all the pages on your website to the target URL and rest of the rules below this will not be used.

You can use `RedirectMatch` with regex match exactly what you want:

```
RedirectMatch 301 ^/$ /www.newdomain.com/landing
RedirectMatch 301 ^/es/?$ /www.newdomain.com/es/landing
RedirectMatch 301 ^/en/?$ /www.newdomain.com/en/landing
```

Alternatively you can change the order of your rules:

```
Redirect 301 /es /www.newdomain.com/es/landing
Redirect 301 /en /www.newdomain.com/en/landing
Redirect 301 / /www.newdomain.com/landing
```

And don't forget to clear your browser cache.

Comment: It's work fine!

But, I have another problem, but, some pages.

ex:

Redirect 301 /page/page-x http://www.newdomain.com/page/page-y

When I go to old url, doesn't redirect correctly (go to www.newdomain.com/page/page-x), but anothers rules, works correctly.

Comment: Use all the `RedirectMatch` rules as I suggested and post your complete .htaccess in question

Comment: It's solved, is the same case, first I Redirect 301 to /page-x and after Redirect to /page, in the other order, doesn't work.

Comment: You should update the question with your .htaccess and as I suggested don't use `Redirect`. Just use `RedirectMatch` as I suggested.